# List denormalization with morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, nosql, morphia

Suppose i have two morphia entities: `Person` and `Team` which are look like this

```
@Entity
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private String login;
   private String mail;
   private List<Team> teams;
}


@Entity
public class Team {
   private String name;
   private String description;
   private List<Person> members;
   //some more fields
}
```

I want map this model into Mongodb database like this

**Users collection**

```
{
    name:"someName",
    login:"somelogin",
    mail:"some@mail.com",
    teams: [
        {id:"teamId", name:"TeamName"} //only specific fields fron Team Entity
        {id:"anotherTeamId", name:"AnotherTeamName"}        
    ]
}
```

**Teams collection**

```
{
    id:"teamId", 
    name:"TeamName",
    description:"Very strong team",
    members: [id:"aaa", name: "someName"] //only specific fields fron User Entity
    //some other fields
}

{
    id:"anotherTeamId", 
    name:"AnotherTeamName",
    description:"Brave new team",
    members: [id:"aaa", name: "someName"] //only specific fields fron User Entity
    //some other fields
}
```

So, I want denormolize **only specific fields** (only `name` for example) from `Team` document into `User`'s `teams` field. 
I don't understand Can I use morphia (or some other odm) for this case? Which annotations I should use in my Entities? 
It seems that @Reference annotation is not allowed with `List<>` fields.

I think, i should create inner class `PersonTeam`, which will contain Team's name and id, and use it in `Person` class

```
@Entity
public class Person {
   private String name;
   private String login;
   private String mail;
   private List<PersonTeam> teams;
}

public class PersonTeam {
    private String teamId;
    private String teamName;
}
```

Is this a good way to solve my problem? thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's about the only way to do it with morphia at least.  You might consider using `@Reference` on those fields and only storing the IDs.  That'd help if your concern is saving space.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What do you think, is it ok to denormolize data in a way I've described in the question in the nosql world? In my case this way helps to decrease count of queries (read queries, not write) , but needs more disk space. Is there some another disadvantages of this way?

Comment: finally i found the article on this topic. it makes many things clear https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/6-rules-of-thumb-for-mongodb-schema-design-part-1